# Карта от Яндекс в модальном окне boostrap4

Tags: jquery

можно ли вывести эту карту в модальном окне boostrap4?
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geolink-docpage/?from=mapstools

Comment: какая разница где выводить карту? куда вставите блок, там и выведется.

Comment: дело в том, что яндекс карта эта очень маленькая.

Comment: какой контейнер, такая и карта.

Comment: она такая по умолчанию

Comment: кто вам мешает обычную карту открывать в модалке, а не эту геоссылку показывать? не понимаю,  в чем проблема вообще

Comment: У меня несколько адресов на странице, вида
Москва ул. Нагибина
Москва ул. Красноармейская. Так вот чтоб не делать к каждому адресу  свой код с конструктора, я просто оборачиваю в тег и все